# Unable to ping remote websites from an ipV6 only ubuntu ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, ipv6

I'm unable to ping/or perform curl to any website from an instance which has only ipv6 address assigned whereas I'm able to ping/access internet if I create a windows instance with same settings (Ubuntu or Amazon Linux instances are not working), some of the details of the ec2 Instance are as follows

ip -6 addr:
[image: ip -6 addr]

Route Table for subnet:

[image: Route Table]

Network ACL for subnet:

[image: Security Groups]

Ping command response (Stuck with no output): https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYY0j.png

Security Group Outbound Rules https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODGEf.png

Comment: Are you trying to ping IPv6 addresses?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, I'm not able to perform any curl requests as well

Comment: Those URIs you include only have IPv4 addresses. Remember that IPv4 and IPv6 are two separate, incompatible protocols.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please show exactly what you did and exactly what response you received.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , I'm able to ssh into an ec2 instance which has only ipv6 address (no ipv4 address is assigned). The issue is I'm not able to ping any remote website from the server. Please check ping command output from image, it's stuck.